# Get user specific information from database using Laravel and AngularJS

Tags: php, database, angularjs, laravel

I am developing an application using Laravel and AngularJS.

My problem is that I want to get all information from a table for a certain user.

In the routes.php file I have declared a group so that I can reach all comments by going to:

```
localhost/project/public/api/comments.
```

I also want to be able to get all comments by a given user by going to:

```
localhost/project/public/api/comment/id.
```

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    Route::resource('comments', 'CommentController', array('only' => array('index', 'store', 'destroy')));
    Route::get('comment/{id}', function($id) {
       $col = 'user_id';
       return Comments::where($col, '=', $id);
    });
}
```

When using this code I get the error:

```
ErrorException
    Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

I can receive the first result by adding:

```
return Comment::where($col, '=', $id)->first();
```

But I want to receive all comments for the given user. How can this be done.

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage (hint: `->get()`)

Comment: I think I missed that part. Thank you, I will read the documentation more thoroughly in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a result

```
return Comments::where($col, '=', $id)->get();
```

But you should serialize it to JSON format (for example), so you should do:

```
$comments = Comments::where($col, '=', $id)->get();
return Response::json(array('success'=>true,'comments'=>$comments->toJson()));
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost disappointed I didn't figured out the answer by myself.

Answer (score 1):

The Router requires you to return a `Response` object, not a Collection, a Builder or anything else - since Laravel tries to convert the respons to a string (like it happens to Views), but while Responses have a _toString() method, other objects might not - hence your error.

You should return a View or another response (like JSON), maybe doing something like:

```
Route::get('comment/{id}', function($id) {
    $comments = Comments::where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
    return View::make('myview')->with('comments', $comments);
});
```

Comment: I think he most likely will need a JSON response: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses

Comment: That would be better indeed